# Apache query string rewrite not working

Tags: apache-httpd, proxy, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite a domain name in a query parameter in order to augment a proxy.  The proxy basically is just a domain rewrite, but some of the responses from the upstream server include a query parameter that is eventually used as a redirect (in the "Location" header).  I need to be able to rewrite this domain name so that it points to the proxy instead of the upstream server.  My current config looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
# Set the path to SSL certificate
# Usage: SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

# Servers to proxy the connection, or;
# List of application servers:
# Usage:
# ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# Example:

RewriteEngine On
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)upstream\.com(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)upstream\.com(.*)  %1proxy.com%2 [N]

ProxyPass / https://upstream.com/
ProxyPassReverse / https://upstream.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

The proxy is working fine, but one of the first things the upstream server does is send a redirect with a query parameter that is used for a second redirect, which causes the proxy to lose control of the traffic stream.  I need this query string rewritten so the upstream servers response will cause a redirect back to the proxy instead of the upstream server.

mod_rewrite is enabled and 'apachectl -t' reports that the config is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got the rewrite module on by typing in terminal `a2enmod Rewrite` then restart apache

Please also make sure you've got an AllowOverride in a directory block within the vhost

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but mod_rewrite has been enabled.  I don't have (or need as far as i'm aware) a directory block as this particular host is only intended to be used as a proxy.  I've included the entire virtualhost configuration in my original question.

Comment: Try add this: "RewriteEngine  on" before the rewrite definitions

Comment: Updated config and reloaded apache, no change in behavior